# Methods for solving BVP for DAE

Tags: numerical-analysis

I look for a numerical method to solve boundary value problems for systems of differential and algebraic equations of the form F(x,y,y') = 0, G(x,y) = 0, y(a) = ya, y(b) = yb, where y = (y1, y2, ... yn). I have to implement it myself, but I can't find such methods in textbooks. Where can I find description of needed method?

Comment: You may want to check the answers [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8048/how-do-i-solve-a-boundary-value-ode-in-matlab) for methods and references. However, because of the DAEs involved,  your question needs a separate answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know a method for solving BVPs for ODEs. In my problems some y's may be eliminated from G(x, y) = 0 numerically with Newton's method, and the problems may be reduced to ordinary BVPs for ODEs, but this seems to be cumbersome method. So I'm interested in some other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main methods I'm aware of are collocation methods. The best source I can think of on the topic is ["Numerical Solution of Boundary Value Problems for Ordinary Differential Equations" by Ascher, Mattheij, and Russell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898713544), in which they devote a chapter to methods applicable to DAEs and generalized ODEs. One package for solving BVPs for DAE is [COLDAE](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~ascher/coldae.f) by Ascher and Spiteri; relevant references for the methods implemented therein can be found in the comment block at the start of the file in the link.

["Differential-Algebraic Equations: Analysis and Numerical Solution" by Kunkel and Mehrmann](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3037190175) is a more up-to-date reference. I've only skimmed the book; a former colleague of mine recommended it.